# How can I filter out a large number of addresses in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I'm looking to create a "blacklist" of IP addresses that Wireshark will ignore.

I'm monitoring traffic originating on an iPhone, and there's a lot of chatter from Apple, Google Services, etc. I never really care about this traffic, so it would be nice to have it always filtered out. Is there a way to easily filter out a large number of IP addresses?

The most ideal solution would be from a file using subnet notation, like `117.173.66.0/24`.

My current solution is to use a big nasty capture filter:

```
host 10.0.2.17 and not net 17.158.36.0/24 and not net 173.194.33.0/24 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to modify the display filters: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAppFilesConfigurationSection.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this section from [this page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters):

Filter by a protocol ( e.g. SIP ) and filter out unwanted IPs:

`ip.src != xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && ip.dst != xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && sip`

Comment: Thanks, but it's mostly TCP and HTTP traffic from the addresses I want to filter, and my current list has 23 addresses. I'd rather avoid using the display filter since I use it often, and don't want to have to constantly prepend a big long string of IPs to filter.